# What is the best way to implement an admin panel in rails for a large e-commerce website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, admin, rails-admin

Writing your own MVC for the panel is one option. The other option (currently used) is [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin), but it is somewhat slow and more importantly does not give all the functionality that is maybe required.

So, how do other big ecommerce companies develop their admin panels ?
How does `rails_admin` compare with `active_admin` and `typus`?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [active_admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin), should be able to solve the problem.

Read the gem documentation, not the link provided in comments.

Also, be aware, that if you'd need to customize AA **hard** - it is not the easiest thing to do, - in such case consider rolling your own admin panel.

Comment: What is the level of customization possible with active_admin? Can I add custom HTML if required?

Comment: http://activeadmin.info/docs/documentation.html this will explain everything you wants to know.

Comment: @SumitMahamuni the link you provided is not updated for like few years.